# How can I derive the matrix value of bond operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, quantum-spin, ferromagnetism

For SU(2), if bond operator is [image]

how can I derive the matrix of bond operator nuder the basis of spin coherent state:
[image]
 I just know I should use the overlap relation of spin coherent state, but I don't know how to deal with the bond operator.

Comment: What is $\vert\hat \Omega_j\rangle_S$?

Comment: That is spin coherent state $| \hat \Omega \rangle = e^{iS^{z}\fi} e^{iS^{y}\theta} e^{iS^{z} x}  |S,S \rangle $

Comment: so then what is the meaning of $b_j\vert \hat\Omega_j\rangle_S$?  Are you thinking of $b_j$ as a component of a tensor operator and if yes what is the other component?

Comment: Reference for equations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am following [section 7.3](https://books.google.co.il/books?id=d-sHCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22spin%20coherent%20state%22%20%22Schwinger%20boson%22&source=bl&ots=U5P29WVW2P&sig=ClBwkOE7T5P6N4tZv0uIoMItl7M&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjm4d_f46TWAhUDXBQKHSTkBXMQ6AEIRDAG#v=onepage&q=%22spin%20coherent%20state%22%20%22Schwinger%20boson%22&f=false) in Interacting electrons and quantum magnetism by Assa Auerbach.

The spin coherent states in the Schwinger boson representation are given by:
$$ | \Omega \rangle_S = e^{iS\chi} \frac{ (u a^{\dagger}+ v b^{\dagger})^{2S}}{\sqrt{(2S)!}} | 0\rangle$$

The annihilation operator $a$ acts as a derivative with respect to $a^{\dagger}$, thus:

$$ a | \Omega \rangle_S = e^{iS\chi} u \frac{ (u a^{\dagger}+ v b^{\dagger})^{2S-1}}{\sqrt{(2S)!}} | 0\rangle = \sqrt{2S} e^{i\frac{\chi}{2}} u| \Omega \rangle_{S-\frac{1}{2}}$$
Similarly:
$$ b | \Omega \rangle_S =\sqrt{2S} e^{i\frac{\chi}{2}} v| \Omega \rangle_{S-\frac{1}{2}}$$
$$ \langle \Omega|_S  a^{\dagger}  = \sqrt{2S} e^{i\frac{\chi}{2}} u^{*} \langle \Omega|_{S-\frac{1}{2}} $$

and
$$ \langle \Omega|_S  b^{\dagger}  = \sqrt{2S} e^{i\frac{\chi}{2}} v^{*} \langle \Omega|_{S-\frac{1}{2}} $$

Performing all four operations transforms, all the coherent states become $S-frac{1}{2}$ states, thus their inner product is one. Thus we obtain the second equality:
The third equality can be obtained using the definitions of the Schwinger boson coordinates in terms of the spherical coordinates
$$u = \cos\frac{\theta}{2}e^{i\frac{\phi}{2}}$$
$$v = \sin\frac{\theta}{2}e^{-i\frac{\phi}{2}}$$

The term $ u_i^{*}u_j+ v_i^{*}v_j$:

When one of the points is at the north pole ($u_i=1, v_i=0$) this expression is just $ \cos\frac{\theta_j}{2}$. In this case, the scalar product of the two coherent vectors is
$$\Omega_i  \cdot \Omega_j = \cos\theta_j = 2 (\cos\frac{\theta_j}{2})^2-1$$.

Since we can always place one of the points on the north pole, we have:
$$ u_i^{*}u_j+ v_i^{*}v_j = \sqrt{\frac{1 + \Omega_i  \cdot \Omega_j }{2}}$$
Up to a phase. This phase was computed by direct substitution of the coherent vectors by Auerbach equation (7.19), giving exactly the second equality in the question.

Comment: I am confused "The annihilation operator $a$  acts as a derivative with respect to a†", is this a trick for any second quantization operator?

Comment: @J. X. Zhang. The identity $a f(a^{\dagger})|0\rangle = \frac{df(a^{\dagger})}{da^{\dagger}}|0\rangle$ is a direct consequence of the canonical commutation relation $[a, a^{\dagger}] =1$. First, please notice that the commutation relation is identical to the commutation relation of a derivative: relation $[\frac{\partial}{\partial x}, x] =1$.

Comment: @J. X. Zhang.  cont. The identity stems from the commutation relation: $[a, f(a^{\dagger})] = \frac{df(a^{\dagger})}{da^{\dagger}}$. The latter can be proved as follows. Since every smooth function can be approximated by a polynomial. It is sufficient to prove the identity for a polynomial: $[a, a^{{\dagger}n}] = n a^{{\dagger}{n-1}}$. The latter can be proved by induction.